# swift AutoLayoutを設定したviewのサイズについて

Tags: swift, autolayout

AutoLayoutの設定をしたUIView上(の中)に等間隔でUIButtonを配置するプログラムを書いています。（厳密な「等間隔」ではなく、はみ出ない程度に配置する、といったもの）
UIButtonは7つで、カレンダーの1週間分を表示するようなイメージです。
UIViewのwidthからボタンの幅と間隔を計算して配置する、というだけのプログラムなのですが、シミュレーターで確認しますとUIViewからはみ出てしまいます。デバッグしてみても値は正しく計算されているようなので、何が原因なのか分からずにいます。もしかしたら何か根本的に間違っているのかもしれません^^;

恐れ入りますが、お気づきの点がありましたらご指摘頂けないでしょうか？

〜追記〜
viewOya.bounds.widthで「359」という値を取得していますが、これが誤っているようです。
実際には「343」なのでこの値を取得したいのですが、bounds.width,frame.widthとも「359」を返してきます。
正しいサイズを取得するにはどうしたら良いのでしょうか？

---

＊ピンク色の背景の部分がボタンを配置したいUIView。
＊AutoLayoutは、Leading,TrailingともSuperviewから「0」に設定しました。
[image: AutoLayoutを設定したUIView]

---

＊シミュレーターでの見た目(「6」のボタンが右にはみ出てしまっています^^;??)
[image: シミュレーターでの見た目]

---

＊ソース

```
func test() {

    viewOya.setNeedsLayout()
    viewOya.layoutIfNeeded()

    let intOyaW: Int = Int(viewOya.bounds.width)    //親viewの幅
    let intBtnW: Int = intOyaW * 12 / 100           //ボタンの幅(親viewの幅の12％としよう)
    let intSpan: Int = (intOyaW - intBtnW * 7) / 6  //間隔
    let incl: Int    = intBtnW + intSpan            //増分値
    print("intOyaW -> \(intOyaW)")
    print("intBtnW -> \(intBtnW)")
    print("intSpan -> \(intSpan)")
    print("intBtnW*7+intSpan*6 -> \(intBtnW*7+intSpan*6)")

    for i in 0...6 {

        //ボタン作成
        let btn: UIButton = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle(String(i), forState: .Normal)
        btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

        //位置・サイズを定義
        let posX  = CGFloat(incl * (i % 7))
        let posY  = CGFloat(0)
        let sizeW = CGFloat(intBtnW)
        let sizeH = CGFloat(intBtnW)
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(posX, posY, sizeW, sizeH)

        //ボタンを配置
        viewOya.addSubview(btn)

        //デバッグ
        print("btn\(i)  minX -> \(btn.frame.minX)  width -> \(btn.frame.size.width)  maxX -> \(btn.frame.maxX)")
    }

}
```

---

＊デバッグ出力結果

> intOyaW -> 359
>   intBtnW -> 43
>   intSpan -> 9
>   intBtnW*7+intSpan*6 -> 355
>
> btn0  minX -> 0.0  width -> 43.0  maxX -> 43.0
>   btn1  minX -> 52.0  width -> 43.0  maxX -> 95.0
>   btn2  minX -> 104.0  width -> 43.0  maxX -> 147.0
>   btn3  minX -> 156.0  width -> 43.0  maxX -> 199.0
>   btn4  minX -> 208.0  width -> 43.0  maxX -> 251.0
>   btn5  minX -> 260.0  width -> 43.0  maxX -> 303.0
>   btn6  minX -> 312.0  width -> 43.0  maxX -> 355.0

---

iPhone6のシミュレーターで検証しています。
親ビューの幅が359で「6」のボタンのmaxXが355なので、親ビューからはみ出ることはないと思うのですが、？です。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

test()関数をviewDidLoad()の中で呼び出しているのではないでしょうか？

viewDidLoad()が呼び出された時点では、各Viewのサイズは確定していません。

以下のように、viewDidLayoutSubviews()の中でtest()を呼ぶようにすることで、想定したとおりに配置されるかと思われます。（testの中で呼び出していた、setNeedsLayoutとlayoutIfNeededは不要になります）

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    test()

    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

ただし、viewDidLayoutSubviews()は複数回呼ばれることがあるため、ボタンが重複して生成されないように工夫する必要があります。念のため。

こちらでテストした結果は、こんな感じになりました。

[image: viewDidLayoutSubviewsで配置]

Comment: 仰る通りviewDidLoad()内から呼び出しておりました^^;
この時点ではサイズが確定されていないのですね...勉強になりました。
viewDidLayoutSubviews()内に記載し、こちらでも正しく表示させることができました。
どうもありがとうございました<(_ _)>